# Cypher – How to carry variables through WITH pipe

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, with-clause

I have the following query:

```
START e1=node:event(prop="0")
MATCH e1-[r:rbel]->e2
WITH e1, e2, count(e1) as ecount
MATCH e1-[:redge]->p<-[:redge]-e2
WITH p.element_type as Type, p.label as Label, (count(p)*100./ecount) as percentage
WHERE percentage > 20
RETURN Type, Label, ROUND(percentage) as Percentage
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage of times the specified pattern occurs in events with `prop="0"`, over all patterns occurring in those events.

I receive the following error: `Unknown identifier 'ecount'`

So I replaced `ecount` in the calculation with `count(ecount)`, and that consistently  yielded `percentage`s of 100%, which I know not to be true.

Am I going about this wrong? How can I carry the value of `ecount` to the `WITH` clause and use it in calculation?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Neo4j do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this query work for you? Whenever I combine `e1` and `count(e1)` in a `WITH` statement, the `count(e1)` is always 1. I think that is because the `count(e1)` aggregation does not work any more when you select `e1`, too. Either you leave out the `e1` or the `count(e1)`.

```
START e1=node:event(prop="0")
MATCH e1-[r:rbel]->e2
WITH e1, e2
MATCH e1-[:redge]->p<-[:redge]-e2
WITH p.element_type as Type, p.label as Label, (count(p)*100./count(e1)) as percentage
WHERE percentage > 20
RETURN Type, Label, ROUND(percentage) as Percentage
```

**UPDATE**
After playing around with your provided console setup I got the following query working:

```
START e1=node:node_auto_index(prop="0") 
MATCH e1-[r:rbel]->e2 
WITH COLLECT(e2) AS e2collection, count(e1) AS cnt 
MATCH e1-[:redge]->p<-[:redge]-(e2) 
WITH p, COLLECT(e1) AS e1collection, cnt, e2collection 
WITH p.name AS Name, cnt, count(p)*100/cnt AS Percentage 
WHERE Percentage > 20 
RETURN Name, Percentage
```

Comment: Your pattern matcher is always selecting triangle relationships. I created a test data set on the console here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=wxx099 Aggregating the other nodes with a counter will always result in 2 as plotted here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qsvane So this calculation is basically correct even if it is not what you want to achieve: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ekxwmu Can you please describe your goal bit clearer including a console sample of the data structure if possible?

Comment: I initially want to calculate how many nodes fit my first match: http://console.neo4j.org/r/yt15uw (I created a slightly different graph which is more similar to my use case). Here it returns 3. Then I want to have this: http://console.neo4j.org/r/5yfaov . This returns the result I expect: 33%. However, I had to manually insert the '3' in the calculation. What I think you're proposing is this: http://console.neo4j.org/r/6bz813 , which consistently gives me results of 100%, which are wrong. Do you know how to carry that '3' as a variable? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes! Thank you!! Do you know Why collections allow for you to pass the variables? Many thanks!

Comment: Because when you wouldn't use collections you calculate it for each possible path separately. That would always result in 100%.

Comment: Although your code works perfectly in the console setup, it fails to work on my localhost databrowser.. I get: "Invalid query:
All parts of the pattern must either directly or indirectly be connected to at least one bound entity. These identifiers were found to be disconnected:   UNNAMED2,   UNNAMED3, e1, e2, p"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36404/discussion-between-zanbri-and-h3nrik)

Answer (score 1):

h3nrik's solution worked perfectly in the console setup example below, however, for some reason it failed to work when applied to my actual data in my localhost data browser. I found the following work-around, despite having a slower query time:

```
START e1=node:event(prop="0") 
MATCH e1-[:rbel]->e2 
WITH count(e1) as ecount
START e1=node:event(prop="0") 
MATCH e1-[:rbel]->e2, e1-[:redge]->p<-[:redge]-(e2)
WITH p.label AS Label, p.element_type as Type, ecount, count(p)*100./ecount AS percentage 
WHERE percentage > 20 
RETURN Label, Type, ROUND(percentage) as Percentage
```